# Same code, different computers, different results

Tags: r, compilation

I wrote a code that displays the confusion matrix. When I ran the code on one computer, I get a slightly different result than another computer. I tried this on 3 computers, 2 computers match while the 1st computer give different answer than the other two.

I have tried resetting the garbage collector, removed all the objects. The only one solution that worked was setting a seed, even though there was no randomization in the algorithms.

```r
mydata=read.csv("dividendinfo.csv")
normalize <- function(x) {
  return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}
maxmindf <- as.data.frame(lapply(mydata, normalize))
trainset <- maxmindf[1:160, ]
testset <- maxmindf[161:200, ]
library(neuralnet)
nn <- neuralnet(dividend ~ fcfps + earnings_growth + de + mcap + current_ratio, data=trainset, hidden=c(2,1), linear.output=FALSE, threshold=0.01)
nn$result.matrix
temp_test <- subset(testset, select = c("fcfps","earnings_growth", "de", "mcap", "current_ratio")) 
nn.results <- compute(nn, temp_test)
results <- data.frame(actual = testset$dividend, prediction =nn.results$net.result)
roundedresults<-data.frame(sapply(results,round,digits=0))
CM=table(actual=roundedresults$actual,prediction=roundedresults$prediction)
```

The expected result is

```r
        0  1
     0 17  0
     1  3 20
```

The actual result is

```r
        0  1
     0 17  0
     1  4 19
```

Comment: Try setting a seed  before the line `nn <- neuralnet(...` like `set.seed(42)`

Comment: Why do I need to use seed? There is no randomization. Without setting the seed, it worked on the other computers.

Comment: There might be some randomization deep down in one of the libraries/dependecies that you are using directly or indirectly even if that is not apparent to you. The differences seem to be a a single case swinging between classes. Perhaps it is a tie  and it is broken at random? In any case if you show the prob. of either class for that case its probably very close to 50% if not right on it.